# Need help to validate existing group of records

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable Table called Table1 with primary key PId and child table called Table2 with PId as foreign key. My table structure is like

```
Table1
---

PId ,  Data1,

1 ,    ABS,

2  ,   DER,


Table2
---

TId,     PId,    Cid ,   Data2,

3 ,      1,     6 ,     FR,

4 ,      1  ,    66,  RE,
```

I need to fetch Cid from Table2 based on the Table1 Pid. Means For Pid 1 need to fetch 6 and 66.

Can anybody please help me to do it using LINQ or any c# code. Please dont mind, i dont know how to format the above data in stack overflow.

Regards

Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would join the tables and select from table 2

```
        var results = from t1 in DataContext.Table1
                      join t2 in DataContext.Table2 on t1.Pid equals t2.Pid
                      where t1.Pid == 1
                      select t2.Cid;
```

Comment: I am using Tables Table1 and Table2 which are in a dataset DS1. Do i need to add AsEnumneable()  at the end of Table1 and Table2 in the above query ?

Comment: Yes I believe that you would nee AsEnumerable() or AsQueryable(), the above DataContext was based on an Entity Data Model so it was Queryable by default.  I can't say 100% as it has been a while since I have programmed against Datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have foreign key relations you can use a DataLoadOption object and you can call its loadWith method, you can read further information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx).

If you don't have foreign key relations, you can use a join in your Linq query. An example for joins can be found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join).